# Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have seen many questions related to my question and also I read all answers but these answers can't solve my problem.

My problem is this I have manage_pages and publish_actions permissions but I can not post on my page as a admin. I have a vast experience in facebook api. I am using facebook page access token for uploading status as a admin

```
$result = $facebook->api(
    '/'.$pageid.'/feed/',
    'post',
    array('access_token' => $pagetokon, 'message' => $posts)
);
```

but It shows this error

> "Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

How ever When I post on page without page access token then It successfully posted. but It posted with user name not with admin name.

Comment: Anyone have a answer or not?

Comment: `publish_actions` is not the correct permission to post _as_ a page any more. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#publish

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe. I Solve my problem by your answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @CBroe, as of v2.3 a [new permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3)(`publish_pages`) for pages was introduced:

> **`publish_pages` Permission** - This new permission is required to publish as a Page. Previously publish_actions was required. People who
>   granted manage_pages and publish_actions before v2.3 have
>   automatically been granted publish_pages. If anyone logs in via v2.3,
>   you'll need to request publish_pages explicitly in addition to
>   manage_pages.